# Method Exists but php says it doesn't

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, methods

I have no clue why this is happening but maybe someone here knows. I am having issues with the PHP method_exists() function. I pass in an object and the method name as a string like so:

```
method_exists($question, "id")
```

I do a var_dump on it and it says that it returns false

```
echo var_dump(method_exists($question, "id")); // returns bool(false)
```

But heres the weird part. I replace that line with the following:

```
echo $question->id; // returns the id number
```

So how could it return false if the objects method works?

I did a var_dump on the object itself so you can take a look and see

```
object(stdClass)#19 (11) { 
  ["id"]=> string(1) "4" 
  ["question"]=> string(67) "This is a question?" 
  ["answer_id"]=> string(1) "0" 
  ["status"]=> string(6) "active"
  ["author_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
  ["created_on"]=> string(10) "1323221575" 
  ["last_edited"]=> string(10) "1324335140" 
  ["order"]=> string(6) "random" 
  ["answer_position"]=> string(1) "1" 
  ["first_name"]=> string(3) "Joe" 
  ["last_name"]=> string(8) "McMurray" }
```

You can see right away its the first one named "id". So why does it return false?

Thanks

Comment: You're not calling a function? `id` is a property, not a method.

Comment: I had a feeling it was something stupid lol. Thanks.

Comment: is `echo var_dump` a typo? var_dump already outputs to the screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That ain't a method: it's a property. Try [`property_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php):

```
echo var_dump(property_exists($question, "id")); // returns bool(true)
```

Methods are only functions defined as part of the class, e.g.:

```
public function someMethod($someParam) {...
```

Properties are effectively variables set on an object, e.g.:

```
public $id = 0;
```

Comment: Thats what it was. Thanks. I didn't know that function existed in php. I saw function_exists but not this one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

id is a property not a method. You want property_exists().